# NullPointerException in regards to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at videostore.BinaryFile.adderoo(BinaryFile.java:47)
    at videostore.VideoStore.jButton1ActionPerformed(VideoStore.java:384)
    at videostore.VideoStore.access$100(VideoStore.java:17)
    at videostore.VideoStore$2.actionPerformed(VideoStore.java:189)
```

Line 47: `if (videosList == null || videosList.size() == 0)`

Line 384:`BinaryFile.adderoo(vid);`

Which refers to the following method:

```
public void adderoo(Video v) {
        if (videosList == null || videosList.size() == 0) {
            videosList = new ArrayList<>(10);
        }
        videosList.add(v);
    }
```

line 17: `public class VideoStore extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

Line 189: `jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);`

Essentially I'm trying to add a Video object to an Arraylist I have created named *videosList*. However every time I try, I get that Exception and I'm not sure why, because I initialized the ArrayList with a size..

initializing the arraylist in my BinaryFile class: `public static ArrayList<Video> videosList;`

Then I have a method named *load*, which I run in my main *videoStore* class in it's constructor:

```
public void load() throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
        if (br.readLine() != null) {
            try {
                File log = new File(FILE_NAME);
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(log);
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                ArrayList<Video> videosList = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
                in.close();
                fileIn.close();
            } catch (Exception i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            ArrayList<Video> videosList = new ArrayList<>(10);
        }
        br.close();
    }
```

The intention of this method is to check if a file contains an ArrayList already, and if it contains it, it de-serializes it and places it into the ArrayList.

I feel like I've covered all the stops, so I'm stumped as to why the exception is occurring.

Comment: @KevinEsche thanks! that fixed it right up. i appreciate it :) post as an answer so i can give you the green check thing?

Comment: If videoList is `null` the second part of the if condition shouldn't be evaluated thanks to lazy evaluation. You should try with a different and safer check. For instance you could check `if videosValues != null && videosList.size() > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` tests the first condition, if videosList is null, thanks to [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) it shouldn't test the second condition `videosList.size() == 0`

```
if (videosList == null || videosList.size() == 0)
```

I suggest you to use safer way to test if your `ArrayList` is null or empty using, for instance, provided method `.isEmpty()` or a different if condition, like the one i posted in my comment:

```
if (videosList != null && !videosList.isEmpty())
```

*Note*: in the comment I used `videosList.size > 0`.. but since we have the `.isEmpty()` it's better use it.

Comment: why is negating the condition a _safer way_?

Comment: I've always worked with negating conditions as a best practice. And to me (might be an opinion but it helped me a lot and I've been taught this way) it's actually a safer way to organise your codebase

Answer (score 0):

As per the condition which you have given, the evaluation of  `videosList.size()` can throw `NullPointerException` if the list itself is `null`.

You should change the condition to something like this:

`!(videosList != null && videosList.size() > 0)`

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void adderoo(Video v) {
    if (!(videosList != null && videosList.size() > 0)) {
        videosList = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }
    videosList.add(v);
}
```